# Django ORM - Aggregate by Decorator

Tags: python, django, orm

I am trying to use the Django ORM to aggregate by a field and SUM up the value returned by a decorator. I'm new to the Django ORM so forgive me if I'm missing something.

Here is my class:

```
class Payroll(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)      
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    ClockIn = models.DateTimeField()
    ClockOut = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def time_worked(self):
        return self.ClockOut - self.ClockIn
```

I want to aggregate by `user`, and sum up the `time_worked` decorator. If I were writing the SQL myself it would be:

```
SELECT user, SUM(time_worked) 
FROM payroll
GROUP BY user
```

When I try

`users_time_worked = Payroll.objects.aggregate(Sum('time_worked'))`

the page crashes and the Django debug screen says:
"Cannot resolve keyword 'time_worked' into field."

Is it possible to sum a timdelta field created by a decorator using the Django ORM? Is this something I should calculate within the view?

Comment: You can not use a property, since the database does not know antyhing about `time_worked`. A property is *not* a field at the database, it is simply something that Django/Python will calculate when you fetch `.time_worked`.

Comment: It is furthermore not entire clear what should happen if `ClockOut` is `NULL`/`None`. THis will error when fetching `.time_worked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to sum a timdelta field created by a decorator using the Django ORM? Is this something I should calculate within the view?

**No**. A *property* does *not* exists at the database side. The database does not know anything about `time_worked`. This is something defined at the Django/Python layer. If you thus fetch `.time_worked`, Python will simply retrieve `.ClockOut` and `.ClockIn`, and return the subtraction of these two.

You however do not need `time_worked` here. You can subtract the `ClockOut` from the `ClockIn` at the database side:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, F, Sum

users_time_worked = Payroll.objects.aggregate(
    total=Sum(F('clockOut') - F('clockIn'), output_field=DurationField())
)['total']
```